# Truth Table $2^n$ law where $n =0$

Tags: logic

We compute the possible truth value of sentence $S$ where it's atomic constituents $P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_n$ may take on the value of either $T$ or $F$. There are $2^n$ possible combinations. Simple enough, as $n=1$ gives us $2$ possibilities, $P_1$ either being true or false. $n=2$ is similarly fine with $P_1$ being true in two possible worlds and false in the other two and so on

But what about $n=0$? That implies there is only one state for that $S$. Does that state render $S$ true or false? Neither? Can we say anything at all about this?

Answer (score 2):

If $n = 0$, then $\mathbf{S}$ has no atomic constituents. And there are not many sentences with no atomic constituents!

If your presentation of propositional logic does not contain symbols $\top$ and $\bot$ for true and false, then there are simply no such sentences.

On the other hand, if your presentation of propositional logic does contain $\top$ and $\bot$, then it depends on the sentence. The possible sentences are things like $\top$, $\top\land \top$, $(\top \land \lnot \top)\lor \bot$, etc. And you can work out their truth value just like you ordinarily would...

Comment: So what you are doing here is demonstrating a lower-level truth value construction of sentences? (I will substitute your falsum with a simple 'F'). Instead of using atomic constituents we simply usher in pre-determined truth values, giving the value of the sentence outright. So T is T. T ^ T is T. T^~T is F. T^F is F, etc. And these sentences have their truth value determined in exactly 1 line (i.e. n=0). If these sentences are considered to have no atomic constituents, then I suppose we have infinitely many sentences with no atomic constituents!

Comment: @NicholasTessier "demonstrating a lower-level truth value construction of sentences" - no, I'm just following the definitions. Look at your definition of "sentence". If something like $\top$ is a sentence, then yes: you have infinitely many sentences with no atomic constituents, each of which is logically equivalent to $\top$ or $\bot$. If not, then there are no such sentences.

Answer (score 1):

You need a sentence that has no atomic constituents.  The only sentences of that form are True and False.  Each one needs just one line of a truth table, so the formula works.  The result depends on which sentence you use for **S**.

Comment: So you essentially are saying **S** could hold the content of either being 'True' or 'False', and as such you need a singular line? Namely, the corresponding Truth-value takes up the line?

Comment: Yes.  It could be a more complicated formulation like Alex Kruckman discusses, but every one of those can be reduced to True or False.  As there is no input from atomic constituents, you just need one line for a given **S**